# in horizon, do I have to "shut off" the running image before making a snapshot?

Tags: openstack

I have a running image of an Ubuntu system under OpenStack. I want to make a snapshot of that running image, to spawn the snapshot later. Do I have to "shut off" the running image first? Or do I need to shut down the image in some other way (sudo halt)?

This question applies to the horizon web gui.

Answer (score 0):

We can take Snapshot of a running instance under Openstack without shutting down.
Even checked in Newton, it works.